# slow query using JDBC, Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, performance, jdbc, quotes

i have an issue with a query in Oracle; there is a table DIT_NUMBERS_ASIG, when i execute a query in this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DIT_NUMBERS_ASIG 
WHERE number_asig = '1234567'; //Quotes
```

The query is executed immediately; but if i execute this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DIT_NUMBERS_ASIG 
WHERE number_asig = 1234567; //Without Quotes
```

The Query is slow, it's take around 2 minutes.

The problem is when i try to execute this statement from an Java application (using JDBC):

```
SELECT * 
FROM DIT_NUMBERS_ASIG 
WHERE number_asig = '1234567';
```

The query is slow, like if quotes doesn't exist.

How can I do for execute the query but with the quotes, because is like if the query doesn't had quotes

Comment: You left out an important piece of information: What happens during a JDBC call when running the query without quotation marks?

Comment: What type is the `number_asig` column in your database?

Comment: Can you post the table DDL

Comment: Look at the execution plan for the first and second query. And show us your Java code that is executing the statement.

Comment: where were you executing both queries ?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see any big difference when executing query as you mentioned on SQLFiddle. I have added few rows into one table and trying to retrieve specific row by passing the value as you mentioned above (with and without quote). I see no difference whatsoever.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68094/8)**

The possible solution :.

1. Consider adding index to your table.
2. Specify column name instead of simply using `*` in your `SELECT` statement.

You may also consider to check [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/sql_overview.htm#i22206) for SQL Tuning.

Comment: There _is_ a big difference. `'1234567'` is a string constant `1234567` is a number. Depending on the type of the column Oracle might not use an index on that column if the comparison value has the wrong type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I said on behalf of result shown in sqlfiddle. Since, I don't have any other proof  :)